# Reference View Partial in Package using Blade?

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php, laravel-blade

I'm developing a composer package using Laravel which contains a partial view. I would like to reference this partial from the main Laravel app using Blade's @include(). What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it eventually. It seems there was an odd disparity of composer not having being updated, and me trying different prefixes. The final solution is:

```
@include('package-name::view.file')
```

Don't include vendor name, or namespace, or anything else (I was getting desperate).